# What does a Token refer to in Android Classes?

Tags: android

Please can someone explain what a Token is when it is mentioned in Classes or when methods need a Token passed to it?

Comment: Token is means of identifying the user's session in general terms and it is provided to the user after authentication .

Answer (score 0):

Token in android class is basically an access token returned by the service(Such as chat), along with associated metadata such as its expiration date and permissions. In general, the Session class will abstract away the need to worry about the details of an access token, but there are situations (such as handling native links, importing previously-obtained access tokens, etc.) where it is useful to deal with access tokens directly.

Hope This Helps :)